# Ubuntu 16.04 AMD R7 M445 Driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers, amd-graphics, gpu-driver

I have installed `Ubuntu 16.04` , kernel version:

```
4.8.0-39-generic
```

Which gpu driver should I use?
I suppose that i am using `amdgpu` drivers (preinstalled).
Should I use `amdgpu-pro` drivers?
Here (http://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/Hardware/Video/Amd), in the table, I read that it will be incompatible with my kernel version.
Here (http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx), I read that I can install it without any trouble.

Comment: Did you figure this out? I am in the same position as you.

Comment: I tried amdgpu-pro and it isn't compatible with my system: nothing works, crashing at boot.

Comment: @Chuck http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx
The 17.30 version now works for me.
I use also kernel 4.12.0-041200-generic

Comment: @Chuck Vlc and any other media player now starts crashing on start.
I unistalled amdgpu-pro and now they works.
Have you notice something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the 17.30 version with kernel 4.12.0-041200-generic